# How to add one day to UIDatePicker() selected date in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, date

I having date picker in my application

I select one date from the date picker, need to add one day to that particular selected date.

Please find my code.

```
var startingdate:Date?
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

let formatter = DateFormatter()
        self.startingdate = datePicker.date
        showDatePicker1()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"//"MM/dd/yyyy"
        txtFieldStartDate.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
```

i need to add one day to sarting date

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar` is the preferred API for date math.

```
let pickerDate = datePicker.date
let pickerDatePlusOneDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: pickerDate)
```